# cd(Change Directory) command on linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to code on Colab and if I take a look at the code its self similar with linux, therefore I am asking how the commands work on linux.
I am still confused the why cd on linux works. If I have code like this

```
cd A/B
```

it means to create new directory right?

after the first code then I write this

```
!wget https://abcd.com
```

does it mean I download file from https://abcd.com and store it at B path?

Comment: `cd` doesn't create a directory. If the directory doesn't exist, the command will fail.

Comment: To create a directory, use `mkdir foo`.

Comment: `cd` is short for **change** directory not **create** directory

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/linux-commands-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 0):

`cd` does not create anything, it just changes your shell's current working directory.

The `!` in your next command is a bit weird, too. It indicates a history expansion of the most recent command line in your shell history starting with `wget`, adding `https://abcd.com` to that command line and then running it. That could be pretty much anything, depending on what your shell history contains.

Comment: when I tried to run `cd ../..` the output is `Base`, then then I tried to run `cd A/B` the output is `Base/A/B`. that's why I though the `cd` command create dictionary

Comment: "dictionary" and "directory" are different things. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: I am sorry English is not my first language, what I am trying to ask is directory